# what is the correct charset for a application/pdf content-type http response header?

Tags: http, pdf, http-headers, content-type

I'm looking to see whether this is correct as an HTTP response header

```
  Content-Type: application/pdf; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

or we should be emitting this instead

```
  Content-Type: application/pdf
```

I believe the latter is correct, given this:

> The "charset" parameter is used with some media types to define the
> character set (section 3.4) of the data. When no explicit charset
> parameter is provided by the sender, media subtypes of the "text"
> type are defined to have a default charset value of "ISO-8859-1" when
> received via HTTP. Data in character sets other than "ISO-8859-1" or
> its subsets MUST be labeled with an appropriate charset value.
> [rfc2068 HTTP/1.1](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2068.txt)

And that [rfc3778  The application/pdf Media Type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3778) doesn't mention charsets at all.

This SO discussion is where I started, but isn't specifically about application/pdf:
[Is it categorically wrong to send a charset parameter with a Content-Type header for non-text media types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913410/is-it-categorically-wrong-to-send-a-charset-parameter-with-a-content-type-header)

Can anyone confirm or deny or point me to a better RFC?

Comment: *what is the correct charset for a application/pdf* - none! PDF files are binaries and `charset` shall only be suplied for textual data.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is no charset value applicable. PDF is a binary format which handles character encodings internally, in a way that's not relevant to MIME types at all.

You should be sending:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

Comment: I haven't read [RFC 3778 The application/pdf Media Type](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3778) but *Find in page* yields zero results for *charset*.